# Setting up Delphi to call a 2 dimensional array in C++ DLL

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

**UPDATED USING PREVIOUS ANSWERS**

I have a DLL with the following header definitions:

```c
typedef struct {
    int32_t dimSizes[2];
    double NumericControl[1];
} DoubleArrayBase;
typedef DoubleArrayBase **DoubleArray;
    
void __stdcall ReadTERFCorrectedData(char FilepathString[], 
    int32_t ArrayLengths[], DoubleArray *AmplitudeData, 
    DoubleArray *FrequencyData, int32_t len);

DoubleArray __cdecl AllocateDoubleArray (int32 *dimSizeArr);
MgErr __cdecl ResizeDoubleArray (DoubleArray *hdlPtr, int32 *dimSizeArr);
MgErr __cdecl DeAllocateDoubleArray (DoubleArray *hdlPtr);
```

My question is, how do I go about setting up a Delphi call to this function?

My Delphi definition of the call is as follows:

```pascal
type
  PDoubleArray = ^DoubleArray;
  DoubleArray = ^PDoubleArrayBase;
  PDoubleArrayBase = ^DoubleArrayBase;
  DoubleArrayBase = packed record
    dimSizes: array[0..1] of Int32;
    NumericControl: array[0..0] of Double;
  end;

  procedure ReadTERFCorrectedData(FilepathString: PAnsiChar;
                                  var ArrayLengths: Int32; AmplitudeData, FrequencyData: PDoubleArray;
                                  len: Int32);stdcall; external DLLDirectory;
  function AllocateDoubleArray (SizeArray: PInt): DoubleArray;stdcall; external DLLDirectory;
```

And then in the body of the code I allocate space for the arrays then get the data as follows:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm7.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AmplitudeData, FrequencyData : DoubleArray;
  arraylengths: array[0..1] of int32;
  I: Integer;
  TempSize : Int32;
begin
  TempSize := 50;
  AmplitudeData := AllocateDoubleArray(@Tempsize);
  FrequencyData := AllocateDoubleArray(@Tempsize);
  ReadTERFCorrectedData(fileloc, ArrayLengths[0], @AmplitudeData, @FrequencyData, 50);
  ShowMessage(arraylengths[1].tostring);
end;
```

How do I go about accessing the data stored in the `AmplitudeData` and `FrequencyData`? They are both `DoubleArray` types, but how do i get to the `DoubleArrayBase.dimSizes` and `DoubleArrayBase.NumericControl` values buried by the pointer? I have tried `AmplitudeData[0,0]`, `AmplitudeData.NumericControl`, etc but can not get to the values.

I am basically trying to create a Delphi version of what is being done in this post:

https://lavag.org/topic/20486-lv-dll-creates-mysterious-doublearray-class/

Comment: You don't seem to be right. I don't see array sizes in `TheStruct`.

Answer (score 1):

The DLL is using fixed-length arrays, but your Delphi code is using dynamic arrays instead. They are not the same thing.

Also, the DLL is expecting a pointer-to-pointer-to-struct, but you are using a pointer-to-record instead.  You are missing a level of indirection.

Also, the DLL expects a pointer to a null-terminated `AnsiChar` C string, not an `AnsiString`.

Try this instead:

```pascal
type
  PDoubleArray = ^DoubleArray;
  DoubleArray = ^PDoubleArrayBase;
  PDoubleArrayBase = ^DoubleArrayBase;
  DoubleArrayBase = packed record
    dimSizes: array[0..1] of Int32;
    NumericControl: array[0..0] of Double;
  end;
    
procedure ReadTERFCorrectedData(FilepathString: PAnsiChar;
  ArrayLengths: PInt32; AmplitudeData, FrequencyData: PDoubleArray;
  len: Int32); stdcall; external '...';

// Alternatively:
//
// procedure ReadTERFCorrectedData(FilepathString: PAnsiChar;
//   var ArrayLengths: Int32; var AmplitudeData, FrequencyData: DoubleArray;
//   len: Int32); stdcall; external '...';
```

---

**UPDATE**: the function takes `DoubleArray*` parameters, ie a pointer to a `DoubleArray`.  So you likely need to call it something like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm7.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AmplitudeData, FrequencyData : DoubleArray;
  ArrayLengths: array[0..1] of Int32;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ReadTERFCorrectedData(fileloc, @ArrayLengths[0], @AmplitudeData, @FrequencyData, 500);
  ...
end;
```

But, there is simply not enough information presented to know whether you need to pre-allocate the arrays before calling the function, or if the function will allocate the arrays for you.  The use of pointer-to-pointer indirections strongly implies that the DLL will perform the allocations for you.  But what the `DoubleArray` contents will look like upon exit is anyone's guess without seeing documentation or example C code.

---

**UPDATE**: based on the information presented on [this page](https://lavag.org/topic/20486-lv-dll-creates-mysterious-doublearray-class/), try something like the following:

```pascal
procedure DisplayDoubleArray(const Arr: DoubleArray);
var
  P: PDouble;
  I, Num: Integer;
begin
  if (Arr = nil) or (Arr^ = nil) then Exit;
  ShowMessage('Arr.dimSizes[0]: ' + Arr^^.dimSizes[0].ToString);
  ShowMessage('Arr.dimSizes[1]: ' + Arr^^.dimSizes[1].ToString);
  Num := Arr^^.dimSizes[0] * Arr^^.dimSizes[1];
  P := @(Arr^^.NumericControl[0]);
  for I := 0 to Num-1 do
  begin
    ShowMessage('Arr.NumericControl[' + I.ToString + ']: ' + P^.ToString);
    Inc(P);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm7.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AmplitudeData, FrequencyData : DoubleArray;
  ArrayLengths: array[0..1] of Int32;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ReadTERFCorrectedData(fileloc, @ArrayLengths[0], @AmplitudeData, @FrequencyData, 500);
  try
    ShowMessage('ArrayLengths[0]: ' + ArrayLengths[0].ToString);
    ShowMessage('ArrayLengths[1]: ' + ArrayLengths[1].ToString);
    DisplayDoubleArray(AmplitudeData);
    DisplayDoubleArray(FrequencyData);
  finally
    DeAllocateDoubleArray(@AmplitudeData);
    DeAllocateDoubleArray(@FrequencyData);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ok, so how do I go about calling this procedure? I would create variables for AmplitudeData and Frequency data and set them as DoubleArray or DoubleArrayBase? Then I would send the pointers(?) to the procedure call? (i.e. @amplitudedata)

Comment: @ShawnVance it is difficult to answer that, because you did not provide any documentation explaining the parameters, or a C example of the function in action. I could make a *guess* as to how the parameters should be setup, but I'd rather not guess.

Comment: The DLL reads a file and returns the array that is in the file. The FilePath is the location of the file. The ArrayLengths returns the lengths of the arrays AmplitudeData and FrequencData. AmplitudeData and FrequenctData are the arrays themselves and len is the lengths of the arrays. Its a DLL that reads a LabView file and the LabView structure is awkward to say the least.

Comment: @ShawnVance that doesn't explain whether the DLL allocates the arrays, or wants you to allocate them. The use of pointer-to-pointer implies the DLL will allocate, but the `len` parameter is not an output parameter, so what does it represent? It doesn't make sense to have a parameter pass in the input length of the arrays, and another parameter return the output lengths. But if the caller must allocate the arrays, it doesn't make sense to pass them in by pointer-to-pointer, either. And how will the caller know how much to allocate, and know when the allocation is too small? Too many unknowns.

Comment: I allocate the arrays using the len parameter. When i try      ReadTERFCorrectedData(fileloc,arraylengths, @@AmplitudeData, @@FrequencyData,500);  i get a access violation, amplitudedata and frequencydata are declared as     var
  AmplitudeData, FrequencyData : DoubleArrayBase;

Comment: @ShawnVance That kind of information belongs as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73254575/edit) to your original question. In any case, you are still not taking the multiple layers of pointer indirection into account correctly. Do you have ANY kind of documentation or example code for this DLL function?

Comment: @ShawnVance I have updated my answer based on the information provided on the other site you linked to.